# Destructured Assignments in a *ngFor loop

Tags: angular, typescript

Trying to loop through a JS dictionary in my markup using `*ngFor` against `Object.entries` and getting an error message:

> Parser Error: Unexpected token [, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 5 in [let [key, item] of Object.entries(items)]

template:

```
<button *ngFor="let [key, item] of Object.entries(items)" 
        (click)="itemClicked.emit([key, item.value])">
  {{ item.displayName }}
</button>
```

typescript:

```
export interface DropDownItem {
  displayName: string,
  value: any,
  checked: boolean
}

@Component({ /* ... */ })
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() items: { [key: string]: DropdownItem };

  @Output() itemClicked = new EventEmitter<[string, any]>();

  Object = Object;

  constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: Angular template parser doesn't it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ended up with this in my markup; ts unchanged.

```
<button *ngFor="let key of Object.keys(items)"
        (click)="itemClicked.emit([key, items[key].value])">
  {{ items[key].displayName }}
</button>
```

Still wish I could destructure the Object.entries() in my markup, but looks like destructing is not currently an option for *ngFor.

I found [this feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8709) from a few years ago asking for destructuring in *ngFor syntax, and they said they would pass on this feature.... but I'm really hoping they consider re-opening it.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative solution is to use Angular's [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe):

```
<button *ngFor="let entry of items | keyvalue" 
        (click)="itemClicked.emit([entry.key, entry.value.value])">
  {{ entry.value.displayName }}
</button>
```

This is a bit closer your original, although the entry still isn't destructured.

Comment: Unfortunately, your field naming in `DropDownItem` makes the double `value` access a bit ugly, but that's down to naming choices, not really inherent to the problem itself.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you don't need to destructure at all to use the key and value pair (though this isn't great style-wise):

```
<button *ngFor="let entry of Object.entries(items)" 
        (click)="itemClicked.emit([entry[0], entry[1].value])">
  {{ item.displayName }}
</button>
```